# PyTorch: Move Weights Between GPU and CPU on the fly

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, pytorch, tensor

I have a large architecture which does not fit into GPU memory, but there is a nice property of this architecture where only subsets of the architecture run at any given time for a stretch of time. Therefore, I would like to dynamically load/unload the weights of layers which are not being utilized between the CPU and GPU. How can this be achieved?

The first thing one might try is call `.cpu()` or `.cuda()` on the parameters I wish to move. Unfortunately, [that would cause training problems with the optimizer as stated in the docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=cpu#torch.nn.Module.cuda):

```
cuda(device=None)
Moves all model parameters and buffers to the GPU.

This also makes associated parameters and buffers different objects. So it should be called before constructing optimizer if the module will live on GPU while being optimized.
```

One example use case would be implementing [ProxylessNAS](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.00332), however [only final trained models are available at the time of writing](https://github.com/MIT-HAN-LAB/ProxylessNAS/) and the architecture search implementation is not available.

Comment: Are you sure its the weights that limit your memory and not the intermediate activations? If the latter, [checkpointing](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/checkpoint.html) may help. If really the weights, it may make more sense to just run on CPU in that case (at least check that option).

Comment: @Jatentaki Thanks for pointing that out I'll keep it in mind. For my case I will run into this issue from your link: `Checkpointing doesn’t work with torch.autograd.grad(), but only with torch.autograd.backward().`

Comment: I've run into a similar issue with a model that does not fit on the gpu but which has the property Andrew described.